Talend bulk exec component deletes the source before loading the destination and simply loads nothing
I'm trying to use the tSalesforceOutputBulkExec component to UPSERT some data coming from a .csv file.
We have about 60 jobs doing the same thing and they work fine, but every time I try to load the information into a specific object in Salesforce (ContactPointPhone in this case), it not only loads 0 records into Salesforce, but also deletes the information from the input file , resulting in the input file with 0 kb.
Have any of you faced a similar situation?
Your experience works for me even if the scenario was doing Bulk Upload to a destination other than Salesforce. It doesn't matter.
What I'm interested in knowing is if you faced that behavior of: before loading the destination it simply deletes the source and loads nothing.
Thank you in advance.
Created a new job fails.
Bulk exec to any other Salesforce object works fine except with this one.
